# Plot subplots from a very large file in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, bigdata

I have 10GB file with a couple of billions entries. It has many columns. I want to plot each column into different subplot. I used the following MWE:

```
set datafile separator ","
set terminal png
set output "a.png"
set multiplot layout 2,1 title ""
plot "camkii.dat" using 1:2 with lines
plot "camkii.dat" using 1:23 with lines
```

This script takes few tens of seconds. As you can see, I call `plot "camkii.dat" ...` two times. I suspect that the file is read each time. This is not very efficient and I might run out of memory.

If I could read the file into some variable (say `foo`) and then plot each subplot using the variable foo. Something similar to `plot foo[1] ...` and `plot foo[2] ...` etc. That way I read the file only once.

Am I right in suspecting the gnuplot might be loading the file two times. If yes, will saving the file into a variable and plotting it will help? Changes suggested to MWE would be great.

Comment: No, you cannot cache data to reuse it in a second plot. If you are having trouble with the data amount you could try using a more efficient way to save your data, like hdf5 file format. Then you can use e.g. `h5totxt` to extract only the required data parts without reading the whole file. Just a guess, haven't benchmarked this

Answer (score 1):

I guess the entire file is read tice, but i'm not sure. If you are on a Linux system, you could invoke `awk` to extract the needed columns (but the first column is again read twice)

```
plot "<awk '{print $1 $2}' camkii.dat" with lines     
plot "<awk '{print $1 $23}' camkii.dat" with lines
```

Comment: Now `awk` must read the file twice. Not sure if that's better.

Comment: maybe its better because the full file is not loaded twice at the same time... but to have more control you should have a look at other tools (e.g. gnuplot.py or python's matplotlib), there you have more control over how the memory is allocated

Comment: @RaphaelRoth I was already using matplotlib. Unfortunately it takes much longer with matplotlib to plot the data (unless I do sampling of data).